# ini_set('memory_limit') causing php to crash

Tags: php, crash, memory-limit

I have no idea why or how this came to be, but for some odd reason PHP scripts on my server, once they utilize ini_set trying to influence the memory_limit setting, cause the script to completely crash. No error messages, no nothing. If i call the script through the browser, all i get is a blank page.

Any hints on this?

Update:

running 'free' returns

```
           total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8190820    7922056     268764          0     565124    6598656
-/+ buffers/cache:     758276    7432544
Swap:      2102456          0    2102456
```

Is something hogging my memory?

running ps aux |grep apache gives me 'ERROR: Unsupported option (BSD syntax)'

Checking manually i found a whole bunch of lines refering to:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

All at about 0.3% memory usage and owned by 'www-data'.

The scary part is that none of the processes listed by 'ps aux' uses more than 0.8% of the memory. And if i add up all the percentages listed, i never arrive at where i should according to what 'free' is telling me.

Comment: how much memory are you requesting?

Comment: Make sure `ini_set` is not disabled.

Comment: Nothing substantial but also nothing specific. But it doesnt matter if its 10M ot 100M. In any case my memory_limit is set (serverwide) to 4096M - i know that's quite brutal, but it shouldnt be a problem, right?

Comment: take a look at your apache error log files, there's bound to be something in there if the script is dying.

Comment: ini_set is enabled and works (for example on setting display_errors), but good point checking it.

Comment: I checked the logs before - there is really nothing in there.

Comment: Are you executing PHP through mod_php or FastCGI ?

Comment: kinda grasping at straws... does anything on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982404/php-cli-script-ignoring-memory-limit-crashing-at-much-lower-number-than-limit help?

Comment: Im running php5 as apache module. Regarding the other article - ive seen it, checked through, but the issue does not seem related. One thing i might add is that my server also incorporates the suhosin patch with php..

Comment: In this case, can you please post `ps aux |grep apache` as well as `free` to see how much memory is free/available ?

Comment: I think the server can't allocate the amount of memory you want and stop PHP execution.

Comment: Even running ini_set('memory_limit','2M'); will cause a crash. Pierre-Olivier: good point. I'll post the results in a seperate answer.

Comment: you should try asking on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember there being a problem with requesting anything over 2GB. I think 2GB is the magic cut-off in at least some versions of PHP.

Comment: I don't think is PHP related, more like a server has limited RAM resource allocated to user that executing the process (web or cli)

Comment: I don't think this is the case because the error occurs regardless of the amount of memory being allocated. Another thing that i noticed is that on some requests i will get a "connection reset" error from the server.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```