# Cannot increase memory_limit with ini_set()

Tags: php

I just noticed that I am unable to increase my memory limit above the value configured in php.ini using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php). I can, however, set it to any value below that and increase it to any other value below the one defined in the ini-file.

Does anyone know why this happens or how I could fix it?

Comment: Do you run your own server? Or do you have a hosted account?

Comment: I believe memory_limit is a protected setting. It'd be senseless on a shared server to allow a script to use all the available memory. So if you're on a shared server, the way around is to ask your hosting company; on a dedicated server, it is to change that setting in your php.ini.

Comment: Zneak is right. You could ask your ISP to increase the limit for you.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that I could change it in the `php.ini` (it is my development machine), but the documented behaviour is that it is changeable at runtime and I want the higher limit for one or two files, not the whole project. Documentation of ini directive: http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits

Comment: don't ask to your ISP, ask to your hosting company!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is odd, according to the manual the memory limit can be set anywhere.

- Do you have Suhosin installed? With Suhosin, it's possible to impose a global memory limit.
- Do you have a `.htaccess`  file lying around somewhere saying `php_value memory_limit xyz`?
- Do you have Shell Fork Bomb protection activated? It can impose a global memory limit. See the SO question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751719/php-command-line-scripts-are-ignoring-php-ini-and-inisetmemorylimit-dir). (I suppose this could be part of Suhosin).
- What does your phpinfo() say concerning "local" and "global" memory_limit values?
- How do you specify the limit, can you post a code snippet?

Comment: Many thanks, it was the suhosin patch. The default value of `suhosin.memory_limit` was causing this behaviour: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit

Answer (score 1):

Check your "safe_mode" setting - if enabled, it might prevent you from raising the memory_limit (allthough it's not documented).

Answer (score 1):

you can not override memory limit on shared hosting accounts. that's simple. get a private (dedicated) hosting and you ask your provider to set it all the way up (although not recommended).

Comment: The reason it is not possible on shared hosting accounts is that they normally have `safe_mode` enabled, which is not the case on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP-FPM

There is an additional memory_limit in the pool config files (i.e. each pool may have a hard memory limit configured), for example

```
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 256M
```

In that case, `ini_set('memory_limit', $value)` will return *false* for all values larger than the limit.