# php memory_limit issue

Tags: php, mysql

one of my script required large memory. and probably because of this I am getting following error

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated
>   42729472) (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

I tried to change memory_limit by using ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); on the top of my page but still I am getting same issues. I also tried ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); but no luck.

Comment: What operation is causing this error? You need to debug your code to isolate what is causing this. Also, where are you calling `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`, local machine? hosted site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's crashing after about 42M, which suggests to me that the PHP interpreter didn't get the memo.  Try the same `ini_set()` in a test page with the `phpinfo()` output and look for the memory limit.

Can you set it in the `php.ini` file instead?

Comment: yes setting it from php.ini worked? what may be the issue that it didn't worked from ini_set()

Answer (score 4):

Do you have access to the php.ini file? Then change the memory_limit value there.

You should also analyze your script. Lots of database transactions? Many of them in loops? Lots of loops? Lots of temporary variables? A clever usage of [unset](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unset.php) can make a huge difference.

Also nice to know: [Performance Considerations](https://www.php.net/manual/de/features.gc.performance-considerations.php) and [Garbage Collection](https://www.php.net/manual/de/features.gc.php)

**Edit (a possible answer to your question why `memory_limit` doesn't work with `ini_set`)**

> memory_limit integer This sets the
> maximum amount of memory in bytes that
> a script is allowed to allocate. This
> helps prevent poorly written scripts
> for eating up all available memory on
> a server. Note that to have no memory
> limit, set this directive to -1.
>
> Prior to PHP 5.2.1, in order to use
> this directive it had to be enabled at
> compile time by using
> **--enable-memory-limit** in the configure line. This compile-time flag was also
> required to define the functions
> memory_get_usage() and
> memory_get_peak_usage() prior to
> 5.2.1.
>
> When an integer is used, the value is
> measured in bytes. Shorthand notation,
> as described in this FAQ, may also be
> used.

source: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161784/cannot-increase-memory-limit-with-ini-set) earlier. In my case it was the suhosin patch preventing my script from acquiring more memory.