# Laravel Model->get returns 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am running Laravel 5.x with valet on OS X...

When I execute the following query, I get the response I am looking for...

```
$orders = \App\Order::with([
    'Customer' => function ($query) use ($filterFirst, $filterLast)
    {
        if($filterFirst) {
            $query->where('customers.first', 'LIKE', "{$filterFirst}%");
        }
        if($filterLast) {
            $query->where('customers.last', 'LIKE', "{$filterLast}%");
        }
        return $query;
    }
]);
```

However, When I execute this next query, I get a 502 Bad Gateway...

```
$orders = \App\Order::with([
    'Customer' => function ($query) use ($filterFirst, $filterLast)
    {
        if($filterFirst) {
            $query->where('customers.first', 'LIKE', "{$filterFirst}%");
        }
        if($filterLast) {
            $query->where('customers.last', 'LIKE', "{$filterLast}%");
        }
        return $query;
    },
    'Group' => function ($query) use ($filtercategory)
    {
        if($filtercategory) {
            $query->where('order_groups.groupid', '=', $filtercategory);
        }
        return $query;
    }
]);
```

Any ideas on how I can further troubleshoot this issue or why it may be happening?

Comment: try to same thing with query method https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove unnecessary "return $query;" in all closures.

Comment: I removed the returns, however, I still get a 502 bad gateway

Comment: Maybe memory limit trouble. Try to increase php memory_limit in php.ini

Comment: ok, I added ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); however, the problem still persists...

Comment: I think ini_set for memory limit not work on basic PHP. [this answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161784/cannot-increase-memory-limit-with-ini-set) Try to change this property in php.ini and reload ngix and php-fpm services

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an error that I found in the

```
/usr/local/var/log/php-fpm.log
```

with the error

```
server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```