# How do I set the memory_limit for PHP CLI when using xampp

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have tried setting the limit in php.ini but I always get the same error:

Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 341351 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

I can work around this by calling `php -d  memory_limit=2048M` script.php

But can't figure out what to do with composer.

Comment: PHP sometimes uses a different php.ini file for the CLI vs the web server.  Use `php -i` to find out which php.ini file it is loading on the CLI and set your `memory_limit` there.  The ini in use should be near the beginning of the output.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751719/php-command-line-scripts-are-ignoring-php-ini-and-ini-setmemory-limit-di

Comment: As others have said I get this error all the time increase your mem limit by setting it to -1 then do what you are doing and change it back to something more sensible when you are done.

Comment: Oh and also make sure you are changing the system value as the root user in whm as the cpanel user will not allow you to override more than this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this at the very top your code of PHP
`ini_set("memory_limit", "2048M");` in your PHP script. Make sure to increase `memory_limit` according to your need.

If you keep on getting this kind of error message of `exhausted memory`. you can use `ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");`. This will set your memory limit to no limit.

> **Note:** This will set your memory limit to no limit. Memory limit is the thing which is dependent on your `OS` and `RAM` not on `PHP`.
>
> **Note:** Also please make sure if you are doing something on your production environment in your PHP script, whose job is to keep on adding data to there script, either in your static variables(**Example:** `gathering multiple CSV's data`) or some arrays, then it can lead to either failure of that VM or PHP process in case of complete memory exhaust.

Answer (score 11):

As **PHP-CLI** has a different ini file, this often leads to misconfiguration.

What we can do, for a «[unix shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))» **PHP** shell script, is to set ini keys on the fly directly on the shebang line, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=512M
<?php
phpinfo();
exit;
```

Then to see if php had understood, using `phpinfo()`:

```
./myphpProg | grep memory
```

Correct shell output should contain:

```
memory_limit => 512M => 512M
```

---

`man php`

> `-d foo[=bar]   Define INI entry foo with value bar`

---

Without using the Unix shebang mechanism, we can similarly pass one (or many) `-d` arguments in the command line, or a dedicated *start-up* script:

```
php -d memory_limit=512M myphpProg
```

Answer (score 2):

The default php.ini file for the CLI in xampp is located in `%xamppRoot%\php\php.ini` not under `%xamppRoot%\apache\bin\php.ini`