# PHP memory_limit can't get it to update

Tags: php

If I run php -ini I get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
```

If I run `phpinfo()` (I use Laravel Valet to serve my app locally) I get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
```

So they're the same. I then run `sudo nano /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini` and update `memory_limit` to `2048M`.

Then I run: `php -ini`: the new `memory_limit` is updated to the new value. But if I run `phpinfo()` it still says `128M`. Even after `brew services restart php@7.4` and `valet restart`.

This is driving me crazy, what am I missing?

Comment: Does ```ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');``` at the start of your page work ok? If so, check for any other ```ini_set```s and other ```.htaccess``` files.

Comment: Nope. And there's not `.htaccess` as it's nginx. But I figured out what it was, I'll post an answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51953782/2494754

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that valet runs php, not brew... When I ran `brew services stop php@7.4` everything still worked. Then I came across [this article](https://cleody.com/increase-memory_limit-and-max_execution_time-in-laravel-valet/), followed the steps there and it worked. I'm still slightly puzzled as to why `phpinfo()` displays that ini file path though.

Comment: It could be because PHP originally linked those files as its config, but valet is really running it? IDK, though for sure. Interesting...

Comment: Hi, Am facing the same issue and the linked article isn't working.
How did you solve it?