# printing a variable out of memory limi

Tags: laravel, memory-limit

```
$bookingd = Booking::where('status', '!=', 'assigned')
                    ->whereIn('mechanic_id', $mechids)
                    ->whereDate('created_at', 'not like', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
                    
if($userid!='')
    $bookingd->where('mechanic_id', '!=', $userid);

$bookingd->groupBy('mechanic_id')->pluck('mechanic_id');
print_r($bookingd, true);
```

When i enable query log, get the command
select mechanic_id from `bookings` where `status` != 'assigned' and `mechanic_id` in (14,15,110,120,121,123,124,126,127,128,129,130) and date(`created_at`) not like '2021-06-18' GROUP BY mechanic_id

which in return

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnMQt.png)

Comment: Try this in top of the function ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the very top your code of PHP `ini_set("memory_limit", "2048M");` in your PHP script. Make sure to increase memory_limit according to your need.

If you keep on getting this kind of error message of exhausted memory. you can use `ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");`. This will set your memory limit to no limit.

Note: This will set your memory limit to no limit. Memory limit is the thing which is dependent on your OS and RAM not on PHP.

Note: Also please make sure if you are doing something on your production environment in your PHP script, whose job is to keep on adding data to there script, either in your static variables(Example: gathering multiple CSV's data) or some arrays, then it can lead to either failure of that VM or PHP process in case of complete memory exhaust.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548976/how-do-i-set-the-memory-limit-for-php-cli-when-using-xampp)